# Serializing map to json without displaying the name of the map in output using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am in need to display following kind of Json response for a rest service :

```
{
    "Server up": false,
    "database running": true,
    "dependency 1 up": true
}
```

For this I have defined Java object HealthCheckResponse.java which has a map field.

```
public class HealthCheckResponse {
    @JsonProperty
    private Map<String, Boolean> statusMap;

    public Map<String, Boolean> getStatusMap() {
        return statusMap;
    }
    public void setStatusMap(Map<String, Boolean> statusMap) {
        statusMap = statusMap;
    }}
```

But when I print final response then in it name of the map field also appears.

```
{
   "statusMap":
   {
       "Server up": false,
"database running": true,
"dependency 1 up": true
   }
}
```

Please suggest the changes I need to make in the HealthCheckResponse.java to get rid off of the "statusMap" and extra curly braces in the output display.
This is the object mapper I am using:

```
public class CustomObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {

    public CustomObjectMapper() {
        super();

        configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

        setVisibilityChecker(getSerializationConfig().getDefaultVisibilityChecker().withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
.withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE).withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
.withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE).withIsGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE));

        setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);

        registerModule(new StringModule());
        registerModule(new GuavaModule());
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any possible change in `HealthCheckResponse`, as you want key value pair in your response which is not possible with any pojo structure other then using a map.

Answer (score 4):

You should use annotations @JsonValue and @JsonAnySetter:

```
public class HealthCheckResponse {

    private Map<String, Boolean> statusMap = new HashMap<>();

    @JsonValue
    public Map<String, Boolean> getStatusMap() {
        return statusMap;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void add(String key, Boolean value) {
        statusMap.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

And use:

```
   ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    HealthCheckResponse healthCheckResponse = new HealthCheckResponse();
    healthCheckResponse.add("Server up", false);
    healthCheckResponse.add("database running", true);
    healthCheckResponse.add("dependency 1 up", true);

    String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(healthCheckResponse);
    System.out.println(json);

    HealthCheckResponse object = objectMapper.readerFor(HealthCheckResponse.class).readValue(json);
    System.out.println(object.getStatusMap());
```

Answer (score 3):

I belive that `@JsonValue` can be of help here. If you change your response to the following:

```
public class HealthCheckResponse {
    private Map<String, Boolean> statusMap;

    @JsonValue
    public Map<String, Boolean> getStatusMap() {
        return statusMap;
    }

    public void setStatusMap(Map<String, Boolean> statusMap) {
        this.statusMap = statusMap;
    }
}

// The mapper can be used like this
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

// The POJO
final HealthCheckResponse healthCheckResponse = new HealthCheckResponse();
final Map<String, Boolean> statusMap = new HashMap<>();
statusMap.put("Server up", false);
statusMap.put("database running", true);
statusMap.put("dependency 1 up", true);
healthCheckResponse.setStatusMap(statusMap);

System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(healthCheckResponse));
```

And, the output will be:

> {"Server up":false,"database running":true,"dependency 1 up":true}